# Impresion de caracteres en una matriz

Tags: java, java-8

Buenas debo de gestionar una matriz:
Pedirle al usuario el tamaño de una matriz cuadrática.
una vez que se tiene dicho valor se va a enviar como parámetro a un procedimiento, dentro de este procedimiento debe de llenar la matriz únicamente con consonantes MAYUSCULAS.
Una vez llena la matriz se deberá enviar como parámetro a una función que la invertirá en una segunda matriz para ser enviada de vuelta al procedimiento 1, donde se imprimirá la misma con la condición que la diagonal sea impresa con “0”.
Ademas de que la diagonal de ella se cambie por ceros.

De momento he logrado configurar lo siguiente:

````
```public class OC1 {
        public static int tam;
        public static String matriz[][];
        public static String temp;

        public static void llenar(){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Matriz De Consonantes");
        tam = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Digite el tamaño de la matriz"));
        matriz= new String [tam][3];
            for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j <matriz[i].length; j++) {
                    matriz[i][j]=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite el valor: ");

                }

            }
        }

        public  static void mostrar(){
            String v1="";
            for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < matriz.length; j++) {
                     v1=v1+" "+matriz[i][j];
                }
            }
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "\t" + v1);
    //        for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
    //            for (int j = 0; j < matriz[i].length; j++) {
    //                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, matriz[i][j]+" ");
    //            }
    //            System.out.println();
    //        }

        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            llenar();
            mostrar();

        }
    }`
````

He logrado capturar algunos datos pero al momento de imprimirlo me brinda problemas.

Podrían aconsejarme un poco mas por favor por que no logro imprimirlo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este momento es lo que he podido plantear al problema inicial, podrían orientarme. gracias

Answer (score 0):

Te faltan muchas cosas en tu código pero te ayudare unicamente con la parte de imprimir correctamente la matriz.

primero que nada en el método llenar al crear la matriz le debes quitar la el "3" y sustituirlo por `tam`para que pueda ser cuadrada.

Algo asi:

```
      public static void llenar(){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Matriz De Consonantes");
        tam = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Digite el tamaño de la matriz"));
        matriz= new String [tam][tam];
            for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j <matriz[i].length; j++) {
                    matriz[i][j]=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite el valor: ");

                }

            }
        }
```

Para imprimirla necesitas hacerlo de la siguiente manera pues necesitas agregar un salto de linea al terminar el ciclo interno

```
public static void mostrar(){
    String v1="";
    for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matriz.length; j++) {
             v1+=" "+matriz[i][j];
        }
        v1+="\n";
    }
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "\t" + v1);

}
```

Ya lo que te falta es validar que solo puedas poner números para el tamaño de la matriz y que sean consonantes mayúsculas o convertirlas tu en el código.

Comment: Excelente, te agradezco, de hecho lo unico que me ha dado vueltas es como mandar la matriz como parametro, del resto he estado buscando y programando las vueltas y demas